# Declare variables in Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, variables, declare

Where should i declare the variables i like to use in windows forms?

```
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     int iMyvariable = 1;

   }

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     iMyvariable++;
   }
```

Running the code gives the following error:

> error C2065: 'iMyvariable' : undeclared identifier

Comment: This is nothing to do with winforms or visual studio - this is pretty much fundamental c++ - if you don't understand about function level variable scope, you need to go back to your textbooks!

Comment: you should define it outside your functions as a global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code iMyvariable is saved as a local variable as opposed to a global variable. Outside of the brackets around the event handler it ceases to exist.

Instead try declaring the variable globaly- near the top of the class, then assign it inside your method. (Note: you must be inside of a method to make a variable assingnment.)

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class something{

  int myVariable;
 private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

  iMyvariable = 1;

 }

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

 iMyvariable++;
  }
 }
```